# UK DATV for visa-free destination country

Tags: uk, datv

I'm an Indian citizen planing to travel New Delhi -> London -> Barbados. Barbados provides visa-free entry for Indian passport holders so no visa needed for that.

For UK DATV, there's a question in the form that says-

> Do you have a valid visa or residence permit for the country you are travelling to?

Yes or No options available

If I select "yes", it asks the following details which I obviously don't have because I don't have/need a visa-
[image]

Selecting "No" sounds wrong as an indication that I don't have permission to visit the final destination country.

What option should I select and what's the recommended or standard way of dealing with such situation?

Comment: Hi and could please tell me how the process for DATV went and how long it took? Thanks

Comment: @karandhananjay this was 8 months ago and tool about 3 months to get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Selecting "No" sounds wrong as an indication that I don't have permission to visit the final destination country.

Likely not, I'm pretty sure they know that you are under no visa requirements from their databases

In my opinion, you have no visa, so you check `No`

Comment: They probably should still mention it in the additional information field.

Comment: Another reason to follow the advice is this answer is that it will be impossible to proceed with the application, which will demand details of the non-existent visa that the applicant claims to have, as noted in the question.